# Avoid adding "include paths" for headers that are not directly #included

Tags: visual-c++, include, project, header-files

Suppose I have two vc++ project, proj_a and proj_b

proj_a contains a header file a.h

proj_b has dependency on proj_a. It contains file b.h that does #include <a.h>. I add a.h's directory in the "additional include directories" in its project settings to build it.

Now say, I have 100 more projects, whose files #include <b.h>. Only adding b.h's directory in the "additional" column does not work. I have to include the path of a.h too.. How to avoid this?

Simply put, how to keep the number of include paths for any vc++ project equal to the number of direct dependencies?

I don't have the option to set vc++ environment settings to globally include a.h's path since everybody else in my team will have to import my settings and things will turn messier..

I don't have enough idea but is there a way to achieve this through precompiled headers? I think they are project-specific and should not be shared across projects?

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies are transitive.  That is, since `b.h` includes `a.h`, anything that includes `b.h` will need to be able to find `a.h`.  The only thing you can do about it is to somehow remove the dependency of `b.h` on `a.h`, perhaps by using a forward declaration for the types in `a.h` instead of relying on the full definition of the types from the header file.

If that's not an option, at least you can ease the pain of include paths that are duplicated across projects by using [Visual C++'s "property sheet" feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  These let you define shared build settings in a single file which can be inherited by an arbitrary number of projects.  This will also solve the problem of sharing these settings with your collaborators.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer Nick. I could have used relative path to `a.h` inside `b.h` and save having additional-include-directories inside proj_b and rest of 100 projects.

Actually, in my case there are multiple flavors of proj_a: 'proj_a1, proj_a2, etc. each having a separate a.h. The other 100 projects decide on which flavor to include by having appropriate additional-include-directory in their settings. This was an issue, whenever we need to upgrade proj_a flavors, all include-dirs will need to be changed.

I got across this problem by removing all include-dirs and instead defining PROJ_A1, PROJ_A2, etc. in the rest of projects. `b.h` does not `#include a.h` anymore, it include a a_redirector.h header file instead (with relative path). Inside a_redirector.h, we have all `#ifdef PROJ_A1`, `#ifdef PROJ_A2`, etc. that looks at the include a particular `a.h` file (relative paths here too) depending on what has been defined.

Now, whenever we need to upgrade proj_a flavors, I need only to modify `a_redirector.h` only to point to all new a.h thereby having a single point of control as compared to the earlier architecture.